# Oauth2 - can hacker fake google app engine requests if he knows access token

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform

I am developing applications on Google App Engine, and am looking into the OAuth2.0 details. My question is the following: if a hacker intercepts an OAuth2.0 access token, can he fake requests from one of the "Authorized JavaScript Origins" defined in the Google Cloud Console?

A bit more details if it is unclear: in the Google Cloud console, you can define a OAuth2.0 client id which you send with your javascript using Google's JS api (complete flow [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js)). Part of the process is that you get an access token, which you then use to authenticate subsequent requests. As an extra layer of security, all requests need to come from a specific origin that you define in your cloud console (see image). So only requests from that domain are accepted.

[image: editing authorized js origin]

But I am wondering, if a hacker did know to get hold of an access token from one of my users, the request would still need to come from the authorized origin.

Can that hacker then go to https://myapp.appspot.com, tweaks the javascript with for example chrome Javascript Console, and use the access token from the user to make malicious calls as if he was the user he stole the token from?

As I see it, then the request is coming from an authorized JS origin, and with a valid OAuth2.0 access token. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, in general stealing the token would give anyone an access to web services. The same applies for authentication cookies and/or headers. To prevent the token from being stolen, all the traffic between the user and services should go via https. The origin is validated within the javascript engine in a browser, if a request is forged outside of a browser, the policy is not verified.

Comment: It depends on the type of access token. If it is a bearer token, the answer is yes. If it is a MAC token or a crypto token (JOSE token), it is not enough as these tokens use signature (and optionally encryption) algorithms.

Comment: @FlorentMorselli How does JOSE token change anything? If a hacker steals an encrypted token, how is that any different from a non-encrypted token getting stolen?

Comment: I wanted to write POP token, not JOSE token. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of OAuth2.0 in appengine, the user is just giving the consent to the application to use the services oh his behalf only. But the real communication is between the JavaScript app which is running on the AppEngine and the Service Provider. User is not included in making the calls it is the app which makes call to the API on behalf of the user.

Please going through the below link to grab the whole concept

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: Hi, i've been through that page, the Java version of it. I do understand the concepts. However the question was more that if a hacker would steal the token, he could fake the request, regardless from the fact being it python backend or from a html page in JS (going directly to google api, not your own app engine backend). Previous comments acknowledge that.